# How to organize classes for multiple api providers (shipping compnies)

Tags: c#

Question is how to organize classes (in this case it's a C# app) ?
Use different namespaces for each courier and common classes put in common namespace?

Requirement is to ship via different carriers (DHL, Fedex, etc) and use their JSON api`s.
Basically syntax is similar for all couriers that we use.
All couriers have shipper/recipient, packages (dimension, weight) and lot of common info.

And finally i must make request to provider API via JSON. But for each provider API is little bit different. Some fields are different names. Some providers has unique fields that other don't have.

Common classes can be: address (shipper,recipient), packages (dimension, weight)

So, how to organize classes and do not write duplicate code? Use interfaces? I have no idea.

I tried also StringBuilder, but it is very ugly and i do not like that idea. Preferred way would be to serialize class to json.

Some pseudo code:

```
Shipping s = new DhlShipping(SETTINGS.dhl_account_no);
//set specific courier related info
s.setXYZ();
// min info to get rates 
s.setPackages(listOfPackages);
s.setShipper(shipperAddressObject);
s.setRecipient(recipientAddressObject);
s.RequestRate();
//user choose one
s.setLabelType(labelName);
s.setServiceType(serviceTypeName); //regular, express, nextday
s.RequestShipment(); //here we get shipping number, label and some id for shipment
```

And the same would be for fedex or other provider.

For now, user chooses courier from menu in application. It's context menu with different click handler for each menu aka courier.

Example json for DHL rate request

```
{
    "RateRequest": {
        "RequestedShipment": {
            "GetDetailedRateBreakdown": "Y",
            "DropOffType": "REQUEST_COURIER",
            "NextBusinessDay": "Y",
            "UnitOfMeasurement": "SI",
            "ShipTimestamp": "2022-03-29T13:50:12GMT+02:00",
            "Account": "accountNumber",
            "Ship": {
                "Shipper": {
                    "Address": {
                        "StreetLines": "example street",
                        "StreetLines2": "6",
                        "City": "Riga",
                        "PostalCode": "1001",
                        "CountryCode": "LV"
                    }
                },
                "Recipient": {
                    "Address": {
                        "StreetLines": "Park Crescent",
                        "StreetLines2": "43",
                        "City": "Dublin 15",
                        "PostalCode": "D15 HXN3",
                        "CountryCode": "IE"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Packages": {
                "RequestedPackages": [
                    {
                        "@number": 1,
                        "Weight": 0.76,
                        "Dimensions": {
                            "Length": 27,
                            "Width": 21.5,
                            "Height": 7.8
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fedex rate request json:

```
{
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": "XXXXX7364"
  },
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": 65247,
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "recipient": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": 75063,
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "pickupType": "REGULAR_PICKUP",
    "serviceType": "FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT",
    "rateRequestType": [ "YOUR_PACKING"],
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [
      {
        "weight": {
          "units": "KG",
          "value": 151
        },
        "dimensions": {
          "length": 30,
          "width": 30,
          "height": 40,
          "units": "IN"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us some example of the crossover; same bits and different bits?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `interface`s. Also use wrappers. All wrapper classes must coordinate with the main interface which provides all data you need to work. Then, when you need an `IShipping`, for instance, fill the interface using a provider. For example, DI can provide a `IShipping` instance. So in all over the project, you will use `IShipping`, without having to know who is serving your requests. If you need more info, please let me know and I will create a sample project.

Comment: Sample project would be excellent.